# How do I restrict control width when using Twitter Bootstrap in standard form layout mode?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in the "default" form mode http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms where the form labels are above the form controls.

However as advertised the form controls are 100% width. I want to be able to control that width occastionally. [image]

So for example in the above I want to have the id text area say 50%. I would normally apply the style col-md-6 to the text box but obviously this will not work in this case due to CSS inheritence.

So is the best approach here for me to create a new class as:

```
.force-md-6 { width: 50% !important; }
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to use Bootstrap's grid. Form controls are styled to be 100% width of their container, so use a wrapping grid cell to affect the layout. Your form markup would look something like the following (seeing as you haven't posted an example to work with):

```
<form>
    <label>Full width field</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="full-width">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Half width field</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="half-width-1">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label>Half width field</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="half-width-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can use any of the grid classes. In the example above I've used `col-xs-6` to create a 50% width column on all screen sizes.

If you want to display the label next to the input, take a look at Bootstrap's [horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: Thanks for that. That means that in my example I would need to use 3 rows and then set a narrow column viz col-md2 for the first row (ID) and then col-md-6 for the other two rows.

Comment: The columns must add up to 12, so you'll want `col-md-2`, `col-md-5` and `col-md-5`